# Twitter bootstrap CSS + jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I just discover twitter-boostrap

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

and I'm wondering if there is a jquery library to use with it.

For popovers, modals, tool tips, alerts messages, tabs...

or for example, use this as jquery-ui theme!

anyone know ?

Comment: twitterboostrap is less css framework. So you can use, for example, this less jquery stylesheet as jqueryui theme (for modals, popovers,...)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is Jquery UI Bootstrap: https://github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui-bootstrap

It's a Bootstrap port on jQuery UI.

Comment: I think it's now the best answer :)

Answer (score 26):

I know the guys behind Twitter's CSS Bootstrap is working on a complete set of jQuery plugins to supprt the framework (pils, tabs etc.)

They are to be released soon but you can already find them here, in the beta 1.3 release https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/1.3-wip

Look in the docs folder and you'll find the javascript.

Good luck!

***Update***
Version 2.0 of Twitter Bootstrap have been released with a lot more features and js examples. [Twitter Bootstrap 2.0](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: very nice information, good answer for the moment so :). Maybe there is no other library at this time.

Comment: and here is the"official" version :http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal

Answer (score 4):

Twitter provides Using Javascript with Bootstrap instructions at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#javascript.

Detailed documentation can be found at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a non-issue with Bootstrap 2.0.  They offer bootstrap-styled versions of the most popular jQuery plugins, including everything in the OP.

There is also the bootstrap theme for jQuery UI project mentioned by others, which doesn't make sense to me with Bootstrap 2.0.  Does not make sense to keep using jQuery UI if you are going the bootstrap route.

Also, FYI, many of the "independent" type jQuery plugins are able to be used easily with Bootstrap.  I use the Chosen multi-select control and some of the various tag plugins with a bootstrap site, and it works just fine.  I combine the CSS into one file, re-style them to look like bootstrap, and all good.

Answer (score 1):

I just know https://github.com/pthrasher/jquery.bootstrapPopover
Everything else is easy enough to write it on your own.

Comment: I know it before. it's just for popover. But for modals ?

Comment: Maybe it's just too early. Basically you just need to create the markup with the right classes to get the modal dialog working.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go over to [their tutorial here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/),
right click on the modal box and select `inspect element`,
copy the whole `div` where it says

`<div class="modal" ....`

and pop in their css?? That'll give enough to start with modals..
If you want twipsies and other interesting stuff working, you may want to download and check the javascript `application.js` that comes with that page too :)

If you mean't to change the colors wherever, you should find all the color settings in `preboot.less` inside the /lib folder...
Few colors like textbox/textarea borders, are however hardcoded in files like `forms.less`,
if you want help modifying them, you could ask again...

Answer (score 0):

Ryan Bates has an excellent tutorial here http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics It is rails based, but I regardless of the programming language I think it will give you a good overview of twitstrap!