# Integrate Twitter bootstrap with osCommerce

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, oscommerce

I'm developing an online store using osCommerce (requirement) and need to integrate it with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html), specifically the bootstap.css/bootstap.responsive.css and the jQuery plugins.

I have already tried a bit, and everything just goes very wrong, styles all over the place, etc. osCommerce uses jQuery UI, so how could I possibly use [Twitter bootstrap CSS + jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331425/twitter-bootstrap-css-jquery)

Or is there another way, so all the elements, buttons are themed like bootstrap?

Comment: God good luck. That does not sound fun. Sorry for being unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a current effort at the moment that provides a Bootstrap implementation here:

https://github.com/gburton/osCommerce-2334-bootstrap

A demo site is live at:

http://template.me.uk/2334bs3/

The forum topic discussing the development here:

http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/396152-bootstrap-3-in-2334-responsive-from-the-get-go/

There are plans to integrate this effort into the official release in the 2.3.3.x roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use jQuery UI if you want or need.

This is a full jQuery UI theme looking like Twitter Bootstrap by Addy Osmani

 https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap/

Demo: http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/